# Бинарный поиск по массиву

Tags: java, массивы

Подскажите как исправить? Нужно найти дистанцию между словами word1 и word2 с помощью бинарного поиска, но загвостка в том, что eсли `if(word1.equals(word2))` == true, то в методе `rasniza`, в `f1` и `f2` записываются одинаковые индексы массива и разница получается равна `0`, хотя так быть не должно..

```
Должно быть так:
String[] arr = {"aaa","bbb","bbb","bbb","ccc","ddd"};
System.out.println(rasniza("bbb","bbb",arr));
Получается вывод 0, а должен быть 2!(Ведь 3 минус 1 = 2)!

public static int rasniza(String word1, String word2, WordsWIndex arr[]){
int f1 = binarySFS(word1, arr, 0, arr.length-1);
int f2 = binarySFS(word2, arr, 0, arr.length-1);
return f2 - f1;
}

 public static int binarySFS(String el, String arr[], int lowerBound, int upperBound){
            if(lowerBound > upperBound){
                return -1;
            }
            int med = lowerBound + (upperBound - lowerBound) /2;
            int cmp = el.compareTo(arr[med].getName());
            if( cmp < 0){
                return binarySFS(el,arr,lowerBound, med-1);
            }
            if(cmp > 0){
               return binarySFS(el,arr, med +1, upperBound);
            }
            return arr[med].getIndex();
        }
```

Comment: А если строки разные, но содержат по несколько вариантов, то для какой строки какое вхождение нужно, первое или последнее? например в `{"aaa","bbb","bbb","bbb","ccc","ddd", "ddd", "ddd","ddd"}` ищем расстояние между `"bbb"` и `"ddd"`. Брать индекс первого `"bbb"` или последнего? Брать первый индекс `"ddd"` или последний? что должно возвращаться?

Comment: @IR42 Нужно ближайшее расстояние, тоесть нужно последнюю(последний индекс) "bbb" и первую(первый индекс) "ddd".