# Найти нужный элемент в массиве

Tags: java, массивы

Всем привет, подскажите как исправить код под правильный поиск - Нужно найти дистанцию между словами word и word с помощью бинарного поиска, но загвостка в том, что eсли if(word1.equals(word2)) == true, то в методе rasniza, в f1 и f2 записываются одинаковые индексы массива и разница получается равна 0, хотя так быть не должно..

```
Должно быть так:
String[] arr = {"aaa","bbb","bbb","bbb","ccc","ddd"};
System.out.println(rasniza("bbb","bbb",arr));
Получается вывод 0, а должен быть 2!(Ведь 3 минус 1 = 2)!
```

Тема в которой я так и не получил ответ, там же и весь код, может кто даст совет как это сделать? Очень срочно нужно!

[Бинарный поиск по массиву](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1112336/%d0%91%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%83?noredirect=1#comment1919722_1112336)

Comment: почему вы решили, что ответ должен быть 2? в вашем массиве существуют повторяющиеся строки "bbb". вы передаете в один и тот же алгоритм дважды "bbb" для поиска. раз вы ищите эту строк по одинаковому алгоритму, то вполне логично, что вы всегда найдете один и тот же элемент (причем не важно какой именно "bbb" - с индексом 1,2 или 3). посему, отняв индексы одного и того же элемента от самого себя,  на выходе у вас всегда 0

Comment: @Дмитрий таково задание. Немного не понимаю как изменить тогда алгоритм поиска чтобы измерить наименьшее расстояние двух слов.. Если в линейном поиске у меня с этим проблема нет, совсем наоборот

Comment: @Дмитрий То что будет ноль и почему это так я прекрасно понимаю, но как сделать так чтобы бинарный поиск искал как мне нужно? Я думал уже разбить массив на два, но тогда он будет считать последний элемент в первом куске(как раз что мне нужно), но вот во втором куске будет считать тоже поледний элемент, хотя мне нужен будет первый элемент во втором куске. Еще вариант разбить все на 4 куска и потом сравнивать места найденные по индексу, но насколько рационально это решение...?

Comment: проблема не в алгоритме, а в том, что у вас есть одинаковые элементы в массиве. я не знаю вашего задания и мне не понятно между какими именно элементами массива нужно искать расстояние, если они одинаковы?

Comment: @Дмитрий Два одинаковых String, например , String1 = "Tut" and String2 = "Tut". Они находятся в одном и том же массиве, но на разных позициях.. Задача заключается в том, что если есть два одинаковых String, например, как выше, то нужно посчитать расстояние между ними, но не выводить 0..

Comment: бинарный поиск позволит найти вам элемент в массиве. если у вас много одинаковых элементов , то это уже не к  бинарному поиску, ведь он ищет не перебором и нельзя сказать "бери 1 или последний элемент". он делит массив на 2 части до момента, пока элемент не будет найден. таким образом, нельзя гарантировать, что вы попадете в 1 , последний либо любой другой повторяющийся элемент. это зависит от длины массива и количества повторяющихся элементов

Comment: @Дмитрий есть такие инварианты бин поиска, например в C++ функции lower_bound и upper_bound, они как раз и делают то, что нужно автору, но в java таких функций нет, так что их придётся писать вручную

Comment: @Дмитрий Ну пока на ум пришло только разбить массив на много частей и сравнивать тогда индексы найденных слов. С большими массивами работать не будет, а вот с 10 -20 элементами, теоретически, наверное..

Comment: @IR42 поищу тогда готовые на С++ и попробую переписать под себя, если выйдет.. другого пути, видимо, нет.. или разбивать, или писать функции

Comment: так можно сделать тоже самое, после того, как бинарный поиск находит элемент. пишите метод, передаете туда массив, номер найденного бинарным поиском элемента и  lower_bound и upper_bound. а метод итератором идет вниз или вверх соответствеено и ищет то, что нужно

Comment: @Дмитрий благодарю, попробую и так)

Comment: В Java есть бинарный поиск в различных имплементациях, например `binarySearch(int[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex, int key)`

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець Вiтаю друже. Да в том то и проблема, что готовым методом нельзя пользоваться, нужно написать свой и чтобы работал..